# FactoryBot namespaced models without class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, factory-bot

I have models which are namespaced such as this:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Vehicle::Car < Vehicle; end
class Vehicle::Train < Vehicle; end
class Vehicle::Jet < Vehicle; end
```

When creating factories for these models, they were set up in the following way:

```
factory :vehicle_car, class: Vehicle::Car do; end
factory :vehicle_train, class: Vehicle::Train do; end
factory :vehicle_jet, class: Vehicle::Jet do; end
```

This produces the following deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Looking up factories by class is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0. Use symbols instead and set FactoryBot.allow_class_lookup = false.

Is there a format for writing a symbol to name these factories such that I do not need to use the class name to comply with the deprecation warning?

Comment: Which version of FactoryBot are you using? I had a go at reproducing this and was able to define your factories as above without any warnings displayed.

Comment: @mikej Try 4.9, you might need to pull it off GitHub though. At least that's were I found the warning message.

Comment: I'm using factory_bot_rails which is only at 4.8.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation wasn't terribly useful as to how the `:class` option behaves or what it expects as its value but the source was more helpful. Backtracking from the error message we find [`FactoryBot::Decorator::ClassKeyHash#symbolize_keys`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/c716ce01b448ce4e0bf855c5a2c63ecb9206322e/lib/factory_bot/decorator/class_key_hash.rb#L18):

```
def symbolized_key(key)
  if key.respond_to?(:to_sym)
    key.to_sym
  elsif FactoryBot.allow_class_lookup
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Looking up factories by class is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0. Use symbols instead and set FactoryBot.allow_class_lookup = false", caller
    key.to_s.underscore.to_sym
  end
end
```

The `key.to_sym` in the first branch is the usual idiom for "I want a `Symbol` or `String`". The `key.to_s.underscore.to_sym` in the second branch tells us what format is expected.

If you run `Vehicle::Car` through `to_s.underscore`, you get `'vehicle/car'` so these should work:

```
factory :vehicle_car,   class: 'vehicle/car'   do; end
factory :vehicle_train, class: 'vehicle/train' do; end
factory :vehicle_jet,   class: 'vehicle/jet'   do; end
```

or if you really want `Symbol`s (or have a thing for punctuation):

```
factory :vehicle_car,   class: :'vehicle/car'   do; end
factory :vehicle_train, class: :'vehicle/train' do; end
factory :vehicle_jet,   class: :'vehicle/jet'   do; end
```

Comment: I may have tried to implement your suggestion incorrectly but I am still getting the deprecation warning.  The warning itself seems to indicate that using the `class: ` option is what is being deprecated, rather than passing the value of the class itself, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: I set up an equivalent situation to what you have and it works for me. Are you sure you got them all? The warning (and the code) say that `class: SomeClass` is deprecated and you should use `class: :symbol` or `class: 'string'` instead.

Comment: ahh okay cool.  let me give it another try and i'll get back to you.  thanks so much for helping!

Comment: still not working for me but it seems that the error is in an after(:build) block where a `create()` for another factory that uses class_name (which I've since refactored to the suggestion above) is being invoked.  marking this as the best answer despite my own deprecation warnings :)  thanks for the assistance

Comment: You could convert that comment into an answer and accept your own answer (after AFAIK 24 hours). That's important information and comments have a way of not being read. Glad to have helped in any case.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can:

```
factory Vehicle::Car.to_s.underscore.to_sym, class: Vehicle::Car do; end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the fully qualified class name in string form:

```rb
factory :vehicle_car,   class: 'Vehicle::Car'   do; end
factory :vehicle_train, class: 'Vehicle::Train' do; end
factory :vehicle_jet,   class: 'Vehicle::Jet'   do; end
```

If you're set on working with symbols, `:'Vehicle::Car'` (as suggested elsewhere) or `'Vehicle::Car'.to_sym` should work, although I'm not sure how useful this is in the context of tests.

Comment: I'd say this is a more correct answer. 
FactoryBot is trying to get you away from loading the class your defining. By using the string version as above you define it as a reference and the class never loads. 
Plus it reads a little clearer.