# Factorybot looking up by class deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a shared_example in a rails application. It's working but I'm getting a deprecation error. I can I refactor the code to fix this?

#### error

```
Looking up factories by class is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0. Use symbols instead and set FactoryBot.allow_class_lookup = false.
```

#### source

```
shared_examples 'a sanatized_record' do
  subject { build(described_class) }

  describe 'stripped_attributes' do
    described_class::STRIPPED_ATTRIBUTES.each do |attr|
      it "strips whitespaces from #{attr}" do
        original = subject[attr]
        subject[attr] = " #{original} "
        subject.validate
        expect(subject[attr]).to eq original
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try `subject { build(described_class.to_s.downcase.to_sym) }`

Comment: `subject { build(described_class.to_s.underscore.to_sym) }` is better as it handles two word class names as needed. For example, for `FooBar` the `downcase` version will create `:foobar` where as using `underscore` will generate `:foo_bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related post on the topic: [FactoryBot namespaced models without class_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437961/factorybot-namespaced-models-without-class-name)

From the link -- updating the factory to 
`factory :foo_bar, class: 'foo/bar' do; end` should work because of `key.to_s.underscore.to_sym` [in this class](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/c716ce01b448ce4e0bf855c5a2c63ecb9206322e/lib/factory_bot/decorator/class_key_hash.rb#L18)